# How to solve the following optimization problem with projection?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

How to solve the following optimization problem with projection?
\begin{alignat}{1}
 &\min_{u_+,u_-,s,l\geq 0} \frac{1}{\lambda} \langle A ,(a +u_+-u_-)(a +u_+-u_-)^\mathsf{T} \rangle+\mathbf{1}^\mathsf{T} s + c l \cr
&\text{s.t } u_++u_-=s+l \mathbf{1}  
\end{alignat}
Where $A$ is a constant positive semidefinite matrix. I need some close form solution which iteratively converges to solution.

Can we use Proximal methods for this problem? How?

$A$ is an $n\prod n$ Matrix. $u_+$, $u_-$,$s$ are $R^n$ vector and $l$ is scalar.

Comment: Could you explain what each variable is? It doesn't seem to be a function which returns a scalar.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Still, I don't understand what's $ {u}_{+} $ for instance. What's $ {\mathbf{1}}^{T} $ and $ cl $ (Is is c multiplying l or what?) etc...